# Unity automatically rotate camera on slopes up/down

Tags: camera, unity-game-engine, terrain, unityscript

I have a Player in first person walking around on Unity terrain and I'd like to restrict the camera controls to the y axis (left/right) and automate the camera rotation of the x axis. 
So looking up/down should require no player input, depending on wether you walk up a slope or down.

I'm not quite sure what to look for. You could probably do it with a Raycast, but I suppose there's an easier way?

Comment: If you have a controller, you could also get the collider you've hit and its normal. But I don't know what your specific setup is. http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/ControllerColliderHit-normal.html

Comment: Yes, should have wrote that I use a Character Controler for movement.

Comment: Get the terrain normal with `yourTerrain.terrainData.GetInterpolatedNormal(normalizedPlayerPosition)`.
Disable the MouseLook script on the Camera.
On your FPC, in `LateUpdate()`, sync the FPC orientation to the normal: `transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.Cross(transform.right, normal), normal)`.
Modify the MouseLook script on your FPS to rotate around this new y-axis: `transform.RotateAround(transform.up, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"))`.
You might also smooth out the rotation with `Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, lookRotation, (Time.deltaTime*2f))`

Comment: If you write this as an answer instead of a comment, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few built in camera scripts. you need to import that standard assets that unity has. And there are a few different ones that you could modify, but they do follow the player very well.